# ListPreference paired device

Tags: android, listpreference

i want to get a ListPreference of paired bluetooth device. i found [this code.](http://code.google.com/p/android-obd-reader/source/browse/obd-reader/src/eu/lighthouselabs/obd/reader/activity/ConfigActivity.java) 
I tried it but i do not understand here:

```
ListPreference listBtDevices = (ListPreference) getPreferenceScreen()
            .findPreference(BLUETOOTH_LIST_KEY);
```

listBtDevices is always null and crashes on setEntries. (getPreferenceScreen is also deprecated). how resolve this problem? thanks!